# Is monerujo wallet legit?

Tags: android-wallet, monerujo

I recently worked with the Monerujo android app and noticed its strange behavior.

- Creates the receive address after connecting to the Internet. This is while the receive address can be generated offline. (It seems that the app developer **intentionally** wants the user to connect to the Internet)
- Synchronization time is very high, it syncs approximately **more than two and a half million! blocks with high data usage!**. Very very slow!.
- Initially there is no node by default. And after entering node, again, the app intentionally wants the user to connect to the Internet.

Is monerujo wallet legit?

Answer (score 2):

yup, no issues.  Same with cake wallet.